# How to display image which was uploaded by Multer when query data with Mongoose of each different users

Tags: node.js, image, upload, multer

I have uploaded an image using multer of each and every user registering on my app  and everything is okay with it. But how to display that particular image in the frontend page when a particular user is logged in? i have saved the images in ./public/images

this ia a small part of my code register.js
//post request

```
router.post('/register', multer(multerConfig).single('profileimage') ,function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;
  if(req.file){
    console.log('Uploading File...');
    var profileimage = req.file.filename;
  } 
  else {
    console.log('No File Uploaded...');
    var profileimage = 'noimage.jpg';
  }
```

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: hello joseph...

Comment: i want to display the  profileimage in frontend of a specified user